# Could really use some direction with this simple project that is using Identity

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I've been working on this after work for the past three days, and sometimes I feel like I'm figuring it out, but then I'm not really sure.

It's a really simple EF setup:

A `MyUser` class that extends `IdentityUser` and the only property of that is a `public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }`

Then the `Messages` class that has an `ID`, `Text`, and `virtual MyUser` property.

https://github.com/shmup/tomahawk/blob/master/Tomahawk/Models/TomahawkModel.cs

I've also generated a controller for Messages.

The error happens right when trying to `manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())` and says 
`Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'` https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS8bq.png

It does have the `User.Identity.GetUserId()`, though.

Specifically:

https://github.com/shmup/tomahawk/blob/master/Tomahawk/Controllers/MessagesController.cs#L31

Not too many hours ago I recall the problem being that I could see (while debugging on an error) that it had my Identity user, shown authorized, but it was returning null with the UserManager, not able to find the user by ID. I looked in my DB and saw a single Message was inserted, UserId being null, but couldn't find out where the users were even being stored.

I feel like you do when you've read the same word dozens of times and then it starts to looks funny, because I've Googled and Googled and Googled and read some asp blog posts and, well, here I am asking for any guidance at all.

I am required to use: "C#, MVC, User Accounts, and EF". I wonder if I should have even bothered with IdentityUser.

Comment: Why do you have 2 dbContexts?

Comment: Does your database already exist with the default Identity table names such as `AspNetUsers`?

Comment: @MichalCiechan I suppose I don't know. It'd be easier to have 1 dbContext?

Comment: @DavidG well, the only table I know of is aspnet-Tomahawk3, and it does have all of the AspNet* tables in it, yeah.

Comment: In your context you are telling it to user `Users` as the table name, just remove those lines.

Comment: @DavidG Ah, all right. Done. Now it errors a line later saying "Invalid object name 'dbo.Messages'". I tried doing a migrate but: There is already an object named 'AspNetUserClaims' in the database.

Comment: @DavidG OK I just started with a new database, doing what you said, and that puts me at: Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.